# Kendo Grid Format Time to AM/PM

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid that pulls data from a sql table where the time comes across as 08:00:00 and I would like it to be 08:00 AM.  I have tried doing format:"{0:HH:mm}" but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just converting it in the sql code by using date_format(time, '%l:%i %p').  Thanks though.

Answer (score 6):

If you receive time from the server, you need to convert it to `date` since KendoUI does not understand a `time` without a `date`. You can use `parse` function in the `model` definition:

```
schema  : {
    model: {
        fields: {
            ...
            Date     : { type: 'date' },
            ...
        }
    },
    parse: function (d) {
        $.each(d, function (idx, elem) {
            elem.Date = kendo.parseDate(elem.Date, "HH:mm:ss");
        });
        return d;
    }
}
```

And then use `{0:hh:mm tt}` for formatting the column.

```
columns   : [
    ...
    {
        field : "date",
        title : "Date",
        format: "{0:hh:mm tt}"
    } ,
    ...
]
```

If the `type` of the value is not a `date` then formatting it as `date` does not work. That's why I use `kendo.parseDate` when receiving the data from the server managing it from there on as a `date`.